# Match two whole words in Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I am struggling to find a solution for matching two successive whole words using Regular Expression. I have a text box where the user can type in their search criteria, enclosed by quotations for exact matches. The quotes and space (if any) are then replaced by RegEx expressions. Here is an example:

User enters: "Apple Orange"

Converted to:

```
\bApple\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,6}?Orange\b
```

Then, my RegEx match would be based on this converted criteria. The instructions are from www.regular-expressions.info/near.html

Maybe I am going about this entirely the wrong way? I am using visual studio. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using? You could use something like [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) or [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/k8b1470s.aspx) in C# instead of a regex.

Comment: I was using RegEx for its ability to match entire words, I'm not sure String.Contains or String.IndexOf can accomplish this?

Comment: You can search for whole words by appending a space at the beginning and the end, although in your case it's more of searching for a phrase if I've understood it right.

Comment: Good point on appending the extra spaces, simple and convenient solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want an exact match when a user uses quotes, then you should just remove the quotes and do a straight string comparison (equality, not contains)

**update:**

Based on comments below, you would just do the same thing as with a single word match:

Single word:

`\bApple\b`

Double word

`\bApple Orange\b`

The idea is that the user enters in the search term and you match for exactly that, so you wouldn't be doing pattern matching for the term itself, just the boundaries of it (the `\b` wrapped around it).  There's no reason to touch the search term itself (all that stuff in-between Apple and Orange that you were trying to do) because even the space inbetween the two is part of their search...unless you were wanting to make it a bit flexible..for example, if the user were to enter in `"Apple[lots of space here]Orange"` to just count that as a single space, then you could do

`\bApple\s+Orange\b`

..but then you're kind of deviating from the whole "exact match" theme...

Sidenote: You said in your comment that for "CrabApple OrangeCrush" you did not want "Apple Orange" to match.  Which is why you use the `\b` word boundaries.  But IMO if it were me, I would allow for that to match.  Or at least, offer some kind of option to search for it in that manner.

Comment: Can you provide me with a brief example using equality, not contains?

Comment: it depends on the language you are using but usually it's a double equal sign `==` as in `if (a==b) { // a is equal to b }`

Comment: also it depends on what you are searching against..is this a database query? then usually it's just a single equal sign, as in `select column from table where column='search term'`  would be an exact match lookup

Comment: This is an oversight on my part: the entered search criteria is compared against a body of text; therefore, comparing the search criteria to the search body on a pure equality basis will not return a match. In RegEx I can search by saying \bApple\b which will only return a match if it finds the whole word "Apple". However, I don't know the proper syntax (or alternative solution) to find groups of whole words eg. "Apple Orange". Using most string comparisons, would return a match if "CrabApple OrangeCrush" exists, which is not what I am hoping for.

Comment: okay then it would still be the same thing...just `\bApple Orange\b`

Comment: I like your point on returning matches that are found in words, as this may be more useful to the end user. I will create an option to allow for whole words only as well.